# Beam WordCount Docker image Fails to Start on Flink Runner with AvroCoderregistrar Not a SubType Exception

Tags: java, apache-flink, apache-beam

I am using Flink 1.10.1 with Beam version 2.22.0. Built the Beam word count example using 'mvn package -Pflink-runner' and it runs fine when submitted to a locally running Flink cluster.

Now, Built a docker image following the instructions at https://github.com/apache/flink for the Beam WordCount example and when trying to launch the job-cluster, it fails with this Avro Exception:

```
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.CoderTranslatorRegistrar: Provider org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.AvroCoderRegistrar not a subtype
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.CoderTranslation.loadCoderURNs(CoderTranslation.java:52)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.CoderTranslation.<clinit>(CoderTranslation.java:44)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.SdkComponents.registerCoder(SdkComponents.java:269)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.PCollectionTranslation.toProto(PCollectionTranslation.java:35)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.SdkComponents.registerPCollection(SdkComponents.java:224)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.PTransformTranslation.translateAppliedPTransform(PTransformTranslation.java:475)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation$ParDoTranslator.translate(ParDoTranslation.java:168)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.PTransformTranslation.toProto(PTransformTranslation.java:234)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.getParDoPayload(ParDoTranslation.java:731)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.isSplittable(ParDoTranslation.java:746)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.PTransformMatchers$6.matches(PTransformMatchers.java:266)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$2.visitPrimitiveTransform(Pipeline.java:284)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:665)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:657)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:657)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:657)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$600(TransformHierarchy.java:317)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:251)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:463)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.replace(Pipeline.java:262)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.replaceAll(Pipeline.java:212)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkPipelineExecutionEnvironment.translate(FlinkPipelineExecutionEnvironment.java:115)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkRunner.run(FlinkRunner.java:82)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:317)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:303)
        at org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount.runWordCount(WordCount.java:185)
        at org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:193)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:321)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:205)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.OptimizerPlanEnvironment.getPipeline(OptimizerPlanEnvironment.java:80)
        ... 12 more
```

Any clue/pointer what might be wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: I can find a Avro**Generic**CoderRegistrar but not a AvroCoderRegistrar. So is there some configurationfile where you specify the Provider?

Comment: @GertKommer 
The pom.xml for my Java project has the following entries:

- <beam.version>2.22.0</beam.version>
- <flink.artifact.name>beam-runners-flink-1.10</flink.artifact.name>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
          <artifactId>${flink.artifact.name}</artifactId>
          <version>${beam.version}</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
...........

Can you share the working version for above entries? I am using flink 1.10.
Other than this,  any other place to check for Provider config file for WordCount Java ?

Comment: The Provider is in the `META-INF/services/org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.CoderTranslatorRegistrar` in your shaded jar. Ive build the maven example from the java quickstart and did a maven install in my eclipse. The resulting shaded jar contains that **Generic** provider and not the one the error is about. What do you have in your `META-INF/serv....` file?

Comment: Btw, I saw you posted another question regarding the same project but different beam version. Does that mean that this issue is dropped?

Comment: Sorry - this is my mistake. 
Beam Version is 2.21.0 for both of them.

This issues is resolved by after dropping the 'flink-python_2.12-*.jar' from the flink/lib dir - this jar has reference to AvroCoderRegistrar - since I do not need python support from Flink/Beam, I dropped it manually for now and built the docker image.

This resolved the issue above.
Thank you for your help.